# Как настроить ptr запись, если я владелец адреса и сам же являюсь провайдером?

Tags: dns, hosting

Доброго времени суток как можно настроить ptr запись, если я владелец адреса и сам же являюсь провайдером.
При проверке через nslookup выходит NXDOMAIN, искал способы решения, и большинства указывают что нужно обратиться к провайдеру. Но у меня ситуация такого что я являюсь владельцем адреса и из за этого провайдер отказывается добавить в мой адрес prt запись.